# Link whole program statically

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, static-linking

I have an application in c++ ported from Windows to Linux, everything worked ok, but...
Our customer what that application running on Debian 3.1 (sarge), I cannot force the gcc version on the target system and I prefer to use new gcc (there are some c++11 constructs, which I'd like to preserve). I want to make executable for now for tests and .so file in future.

I decide to compile my procect statically.

when I run:

```
g++ -static -o prog obj/sublib1/file1.o obj/sublib1/file2.o obj/sublib2/file1.o obj/sublib2/file2.o (...) -L../somedir -s -lsomestaticlib
```

I get en error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../i586-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../i586-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
```

The system is OpenSuse 13.1 32bit, uname -a:

```
Linux linux-zfaz.site 3.11.6-4-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Oct 30 18:04:56 UTC 2013 (e6d4a27) i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

The problem is probably with math library and C library. The dynamic version of both libraries are in /lib directory.

(probably doesn't matter: I was trying to build it using code::blocks, but when problem occurred I've moved to terminal)

Do I need to install static version of these libraries? How?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent version of g++, the option `-static-libstdc++` should be all you need.  This will ensure that the g++ libraries are linked statically, but that the system libraries (for which there usually isn't a static version) are linked dynamically.  (Don't use the `-static` in this case.)

Comment: This solution gives me errors in old Debian: `./prog: /lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version 'GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by ./sarmata_c++)` . Using both `-static-libstdc++` and `-static-libgcc` gives me: `./prog: relocation error: ./prog: undefined symbol: _ZNSt8time_getIwSt19istreambuf_iteratorIwSt11char_traitsIwEEE2idE`

Comment: You _don't_ want `-static_libgcc`, at least on a Linux system (and probably nowhere).  For various historical reasons, unless I'm mistaken, `libgcc` also covers the traditional `libc`, which should never be statically linked.  As for the rest, I've had problems with versionning as well; I think it has to do with the way g++ and libstdc++ are installed, but I've never had the occasion to follow up on it and find out.  (Note too that the support for `-static-libstdc++` is very recent; older versions of g++/libstdc++ may not support it, or may not support it correctly.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `glibc-devel-static` package, though if applicable the answer of @jameskanze is a better option.

Comment: This answer would probably work (thanks!), but it doesn't cause: `FATAL: kernel too old`, it seems that need to get rid of c++11 features, and try to recompile it on Debian 3.1.